# Feature discovery animations for Android

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

Since May, Google has updated their Material Design guidelines on their website. I have seen an interesting and cool design pattern in one of the new sections named [Feature discovery](https://www.google.com/design/spec/growth-communications/feature-discovery.html#feature-discovery-design-patterns).

I would like to implement [the animation for 'discovering' the Navigation Drawer button](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B4kv-3uZbS1qM2QtX2xJem50NUk/engagement-featurediscovery-single-flow.webm). There is a similar animation in the last update of Google Fit, for the navigation drawer and floating action button.

As often, for Android animations, Google provide a nice and awesome UI guideline, but we don't have any further information for developing it for our own apps.

Do you know if there are native solutions with Android libraries to implement these kind of animations? If yes, is it available for below Android 5.0 (API 21)  - it can be above Android 4.1+?

Edit : I made a Github project to realise the same animation. You can find it here : https://github.com/Guimareshh/Feature-discovery-animations

Thanks !

Comment: anyone.. please put bounty on this please.. tq..

Comment: Hello have u done it..??

Comment: @Hardeep not exactly like the animation we can see in Google design website, but it's almost the same. I need a bit more time to finish it. It should be done this week, I will upload a Github project and edit this post for more information.

Comment: @Guimareshh Thanks for the reply.I am also working on the same,Will update once i will finish. :)

Comment: There's a very similar feature library called [HintCase](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3707) released on [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/). Worthy a check out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make custom animation or else you can use [Ripple Effect + Reveal](http://trickyandroid.com/simple-ripple-reveal-elevation-tutorial/) and set it to navigation drawer icon,

[Circular Reveal Animation](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Circular-Reveal-Animation)

```
void enterReveal() {
    // previously invisible view
    final View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = myView.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    int cy = myView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight()) / 2;

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator anim =
        ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

    // make the view visible and start the animation
    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this animation will help me to create what I want. I'm going to create a sample on Github, I will share it in this post !

Answer (score 5):

Answering your question, Google always provides new samples of interesting Widget Components. Most of them will be added only to a new version of Android. And there are different reasons for that. For example because new widgets use resources and work only on the new version of Android, that has an updated UI engine. And other...

That is why, there is no Google official Reveal animation, which works only on Android 5.0 >.

But there are a lot of backports for that:

- [CircularReveal](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal)
- [ViewRevealAnimator](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ViewRevealAnimator)

**Take a look all available and not official backports for Android [Awesome Android UI](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui).**

When Google introduced Android Material - there wasn't any library for all that elements. But in short time, by different devs were written many useful libs. But after that popularity, Google introduce all library for that widgets.

---

So as a result, there are no backports and most likely Google will not introduce that widgets. But listening your question, I think you can do it, using not official backports, linked above.

Answer (score 4):

I have also created this DesignPattern in a custom View. You can find it [here](https://github.com/Cilenco/FeatureDiscovery). Please note that this is my first published custom View and it is still under development (so their might be some bugs and a bit of the documentation is missing) but it should be good enough for daily use.

To use it add the library to your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.cilenco.libraries:featurediscovery:1.0.2'     or
compile 'com.cilenco.libraries:featurediscovery:+'         always newest version
```

After that you are able to create a DiscoveryView like this. Checkout all the other functions to adjust the look and the control over the View.

```
DiscoveryView discoveryView = new DiscoveryView.Builder(context, view)
.setPrimaryText(R.string.header)
.setSecondaryText(R.string.description)
.setOnClickListener(this)
.build();

discoveryView.show();
```

To make this view even better please feel free to report issues and make pull requests to the repository if you find any bugs or have any new ideas for it.